# I'm having issues with Maven

Tags: java, maven, path

I just recently started learning Java and I'm trying to work on my first project with Maven (never used it before). However, I cannot seem to get Maven to work properly.

I am running Windows 11. I downloaded Maven and added it's bin to my system's path variable. When I check which version I have on the command line, I get the correct answer, but then I get a message about how cmd is not a valid command.
[Picture of System Path variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuaP8.png)

[Picture of System Path variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2et5.png)

My project's distribution says that I should be able to do a test run of the project right away. However I get the following error message after entering my test:

```
PS C:\Users\tayot\IdeaProjectmvn test -Dtest=WebCrawlerTest -DcrawlerImplementations=com.udacity.webcrawler.SequentialWebCrawler
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.udacity.webcrawler:udacity-webcrawler:jar:1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.110 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-11T10:52:19-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".udacity.webcrawler.SequentialWebCrawler". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
PS C:\Users\tayot\IdeaProjects\cd0381-advanced-java-programming-techniques-projectstarter-master\starter\webcrawler> mvn test -Dtest=WebCrawlerTest -DcrawlerImplementations=com.udacity.webcrawler.SequentialWebCrawler
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.udacity.webcrawler:udacity-webcrawler:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ line 75, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------< com.udacity.webcrawler:udacity-webcrawler >--------------
[INFO] Building udacity-webcrawler 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.112 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-11T11:05:24-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".udacity.webcrawler.SequentialWebCrawler". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>
:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile
, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
PS C:\Users\tayot\IdeaProjects\cd0381-advanced-java-programming-techniques-projectstarter-master\starter\webcrawler> mvn -e test -Dtest=WebCrawlerTest -DcrawlerImplementations=com.udacity.webcrawler.SequentialWebCrawler 
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.udacity.webcrawler:udacity-webcrawler:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ line 75, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------< com.udacity.webcrawler:udacity-webcrawler >--------------
[INFO] Building udacity-webcrawler 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.106 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-11T11:05:54-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".udacity.webcrawler.SequentialWebCrawler". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>
:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile
, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException: Unknown lifecycle phase ".udacity.webcrawler.SequentialWebCrawler". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in th
operable program or batch file.
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. Here is the what the pom.xml file looks like:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/15ueL7GRSifOK0IVvC7V7ueYiL8QCMfWi0r6XtKlWeNI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please repost the stack trace as formatted text so it's legible. Please also provide your OS and environment.

Comment: The Windows command line (cannot remember if it is CMD or Powershell) has problems with equal signs.  Can you try with the other?

Comment: What do I replace the equal sign with? Also, I'm still unsure about why it keeps giving the  "'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file" message

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in the following command line option:

`-DcrawlerImplementations=com.udacity.webcrawler.SequentialWebCrawler`

However, the error message indicates that it's only getting part of that. You can see that the `com` has been truncated:

`Unknown lifecycle phase ".udacity.webcrawler.SequentialWebCrawler"`

Try wrapping it in double quotes:

`"-DcrawlerImplementations=com.udacity.webcrawler.SequentialWebCrawler"`

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question is incomplete and there is no minimal reproducible example, here is a solution that worked for me in a similar situation.

I just wrapped the value of `-DcrawlerImplementations` parameter in single quotes (').

In your situation try something like this command below:

`mvn test -Dtest=WebCrawlerTest -DcrawlerImplementations='com.udacity.webcrawler.SequentialWebCrawler'`